# Account controller mvc2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

i want to modify account controller add some field are useraddress contactno and panno in Register aspx from i want to username, password, Emailid are store in account table and anothe data userAddress, contactno, userName Emailid,panno are store in our table the controller store two table value at the same time.the username and emailid store both table account and userdetails table  what code i written in account controller and my repository plz help me

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following...

1) In your model (ModifyAccountModel with a bit of luck) add the new fields

2) In your controller, you will need to change the code that populates the model with the existing account data

3) In your view, you will need to add form elements to display the data to be edited.

4) When the form is submitted, the ModifyAccountModel will pick up the new values from the form, so you will just need to ensure that whatever you use to persist this data will take those fields and store them.